# Upload images to folder using Javascript

Tags: javascript

On the admin panel I upload some photos and a thumbnail and on the site I have a digital showcase that is built using javascript in order to grab photos from a folder and display them. My question is: how can I put the photos after I saved them on that specific folder? More exactly...how can I upload the images into my folder?

```
if(x.showcase_gallery_type=='image'){
$('#modal-popup .content .slide .context ul').append('<li style="text-align:center;padding-left:5px;"><img src="<?=base_url()?
/resources/media/showcase/image/'+x.showcase_gallery_filename+'" /></li>');
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have done upto now?

Comment: f(x.showcase_gallery_type=='image'){
     $('#modal-popup .content .slide .context ul').append('<li style="text-align:center;padding-left:5px;"><img src="<?=base_url()?>/resources/media/showcase/image/'+x.showcase_gallery_filename+'" /></li>');

Comment: @Mitik-The easiest way to do is try to use uploaders which can do lot of things that you can't do it manually.

Comment: but can't I do this with php and javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Javascript (with uploadify or other tools) can only handle one side of the upload process, namely sending the file.

To receive the file on the server and save it, you'll have to use server-side technology like PHP, ASP.NET, Python etc.

Answer (score 0):

you should use [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/)

and in the handler( in asp.net for example) you should use

```
Request.File
```

and use

the `SaveAs` function

using `Server.MapPath` function

```
if (context.Request.Files == null || context.Request.Files.Count == 0) throw new Exception("error reciving file");

var savedFile = context.Server.MapPath(@"~/Pics/Links/") + guid + ".jpg";
resizedImage.Save(savedFile, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try [Plupload](https://www.plupload.com/) which has several options which suits your needs.

And try this if you need thumbnails to display while uploading

```
http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/
```

*Note:*  This dosen't upload multiple files in IE.

Comment: but can't I write a function or something in order to do this in javascript?

Comment: No javascript is a client side functionality in order to do what you need you need server side scripting.